# c# Mouse click simulation to hwnd at x/y position

Tags: c#, winapi, mouse

at the last 3 Days I found a lot of code for simulating mouse clicks to other windows. but none of them has worked. 
I have the window handle hwnd and the X/Y position (pixel) where the click has to be.
The X/Y position is the position inside the window.

The best code I've found is this:

```
public void click(IntPtr hWnd, int x, int y)
{        
    RECT rec = new RECT();
    GetWindowRect(hWnd, ref rec);
    int newx = x - rec.Left;
    int newy = y - rec.Top;

    SendMessage(hWnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 1, ((newy << 0x10) | newx));
    SendMessage(hWnd, WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, ((newy << 0x10) | newx));
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RECT
{
    public int Left;
    public int Top;
    public int Right;
    public int Bottom;
}

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr A_0, int A_1, int A_2, int A_3);


[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, ref RECT lpRect);
```

But it does not work 100% correctly.
It simulates a mouseclick at the correct window, but at the position of my real cursor.
And after this click my mouse jumps to a random position on the screen.
I hope someone has a working code and a small description how it works.

Thanks

Comment: You fake input using the SendInput function. Most likely you are mistaken in your belief that faking input is the solution to your problem.

Comment: can you post a little bit of code? I am new at c# and I've no idear  how the Winapi works

Comment: It would be best if you explained why you asked the question

Comment: I found some examples of sendinput... there were no hwnd to give in. so you can not send the click to a window it is only to simulate desktop clicks

Answer (score 2):

Use this code to simulate the left mouse click in a certain position

```
//This is a replacement for Cursor.Position in WinForms
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetCursorPos(int x, int y);

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern void mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int cButtons, int dwExtraInfo);

public const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
public const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;

//This simulates a left mouse click
public static void LeftMouseClick(int xpos, int ypos)
{
    SetCursorPos(xpos, ypos);
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, xpos, ypos, 0, 0);
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, xpos, ypos, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I need to send the click to a window which is in the background

Comment: hi @Thomas .. i wish to know the answer too. if you have it mind to share with me? because i'm able to get the window handle, but if the program go to back ground or any other message pop up. my program will not work.